# How do I read and write smart quotes (and other silly characters) in C#

Tags: c#, unicode, encoding, ascii, stringbuilder

I'm writing a program that reads all the text in a file into a string, loops over that string looking at the characters, and then appends the characters back to another string using a Stringbuilder. The issue I'm having is when it's written back out, the special characters such as `“` and `”` , come out looking like `ï¿½` characters instead. I don't need to do a conversion, I just want it written back out the way I read it in:

```
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    string text = File.ReadAllText(filePath);
    for (int i = 0; i < text.Length; ++i) {
        if (text[i] != '{') {  // looking for opening curly brace
            sb.Append(text[i]);
            continue;
        }
        // Do stuff
    }
    File.WriteAllText(destinationFile, sb.ToString());
```

I tried using different Encodings (UTF-8, UTF-16, ASCII), but then it just came out even worse; I started getting question mark symbols and Chinese characters (yes, a bit of a shotgun approach, but I was just experimenting).
I did read this article: http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html
...but it didn't really explain why I was seeing what I saw, unless in C#, the reader starts cutting off bits when it hits weird characters like that. Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: If you debug this and step over the File.ReadAllText line, does the 'text' variable have the correct data or is it wonky?

Comment: I posted some ideas as a potential answer.  Please have a look and let me know what you find ...

Comment: @taylorjonl It's wonky, all the non-utf-8 characters have a � character in its place

Answer (score 13, accepted):

TL;DR that is definitely not UTF-8 and you are not even using UTF-8 to read the resulting file. Read as Windows1252, write as Windows1252 (If you are going to use the same viewing method to view the resulting file)

---

Well let's first just say that there is no way a file made by a regular user will be in UTF-8.  Not all programs in windows even support it (excel, notepad..), let alone have it as default encoding (even most *developer* tools don't default to utf-8, which drives me insane). Since a lot of developers don't understand that such a thing as encoding even exists, then what chances do regular users have of saving their files in an utf-8 hostile environment?

This is where your problems first start. According to [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143368.aspx), the overload you are using `File.ReadAllText(filePath);` can only detect UTF-8 or UTF-32.

Indeed, simply reading a file encoded normally in Windows-1252 that contains `"a”a"` results in a string `"a�a"`, where `�` is the [unicode replacement character](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specials_(Unicode_block)#Replacement_character) (Read the wikipedia section, it describes exactly the situation you are in!) used to replace invalid bytes. When the replacement character is again encoded as UTF-8, and interpreted as Windows-1252, you will see `ï¿½` because the bytes for `�` in UTF-8 are `0xEF, 0xBF, 0xBD` which are the bytes for `ï¿½` in Windows-1252.

So read it as Windows-1252 and you're half-way there:

```
Encoding windows1252 = Encoding.GetEncoding("Windows-1252");
String result = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\myfile.txt", windows1252);
Console.WriteLine(result); //Correctly prints "a”a" now
```

Because you saw `ï¿½`, the tool you are viewing the newly made file with is also using Windows-1252. So if the goal is to have the file show correct characters in that tool, you must encode the output as Windows-1252:

```
Encoding windows1252 = Encoding.GetEncoding("Windows-1252");
File.WriteAllText(@"C:\myFile", sb.toString(), windows1252);
```

Comment: Woah, thanks, that was a really thorough answer! And thanks for showing me those articles as well! Sorry if the question was a bit verbose, just didn't want to seem like I didn't do any research. I'll upvote this when I have enough rep to do so.

Comment: kind of a drop in the bucket, but hey! +1 @Esailija

Comment: @User1234567890 no the `tl;dr` is for a summarisation of my answer :P

Comment: Five years later, and this is still the best answer for this question and only has six upvotes :(

Answer (score 3):

Chances are the text will be UTF8.

```
File.ReadAllText(filePath, Encoding.UTF8)
```

coupled with

```
File.WriteAllText(destinationFile, sb.ToString(), Encoding.UTF8)
```

should cover off dealing with the Unicode characters. If you do one or the other you're going to get garbage output, both or nothing.